# How to prioritise one function over another in an Azure Function App?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I've created an Azure Function App which is triggered from Azure Service Bus Queues. The Service Bus has two queues in it and there is a function with a trigger for each of the queues. The Function App is developed using C# in Visual Studio and uses package deployment publishing.

What I would like to do is be able to indicate that one function/trigger should be processed before the other if they both have messages waiting. (They both do basically the same thing but one queue is for handling messages with a higher priority since queues are only FIFO.)

I have read that functions are [processed in alphabetical order](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3153#issuecomment-1073158123) but that doesn't feel like something to rely on really.

Is there any way to explicitly indicate a priority (or even a scale-out preference) for one function/trigger over another?

Comment: Are the messages somehow related, given your requirement? If the message frequency on both queues is high or roughly the same how should the system respond? What if the low priority queue can never process the messages due to the high priority queue is always busy?

Comment: I believe, you can use Azure Durable Functions - Function Chaining feature to prioritize the functions in your custom order and process it one by one according to your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

> (They both do basically the same thing but one queue is for handling messages with a higher priority since queues are only FIFO.)

The above scenario looks like competing consumers which has a dedicated design pattern known as [competing consumers pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/competing-consumers) where it contains the [limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/competing-consumers#issues-and-considerations) with the messaging order in this pattern.

Consumer service instances may receive messages in any order, and this order need not correspond to the order in which the messages were created.

So unfortunately, it's not possible to prioritize one function over another function listening to the Service Bus queue.

You can control the activity function & orchestrator but not the starter function using the Azure Durable Functions.

> Microsoft Azure Service Bus Queues can implement guaranteed first-in-first-out ordering of messages by using message sessions. For more information, see [Messaging Patterns Using Sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2012/december/azure-insider-microsoft-azure-service-bus-messaging-patterns-using-sessions).